# Sharepoint Site is not Visible over the Internet

Tags: networking, sharepoint, internet

I have a sharepoint website sitting on a server that is supposed to be accessed over the internet.  Inside the server, everything seems to working fine.

If I try to access it from outside of the network, I get an "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error.  IT assures me that the address is mapped correctly.  When I type in http://ourwebsite.com the header gets change to servername/Pages/Default.aspx as expected, but I get the error instead of having the page load.  If I swap out the sharepoint for a static html webpage, it loads without issue, so I know this problem is sharepoint specific.

I've searched around on the internet, but everything I try doesn't appear to work.

So, what are the steps that need to be taken to change a sharepoint site from being internal only to being viewable over the internet?

Using Sharepoint 3 on Windows 2003 R2, IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first i thought firewall and as a golden rule telnet to external ip port 80 anyhow after reading this i am seeing the problem may be alternative access mapping.

take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173.aspx for an explanation, this should do the trick.

Comment: That's the ticket!  I'd vote you up, but I only have 3 rep.  :(
Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem as a result of setting up our Sharepoint instance at http://wss instead of http://wss.ourdomain.com.

In our case, since our site was only to be accessed by staff, we simply added an entry to each person's hosts file that mapped the address of the unqualified "wss" to our IP address.

However, making the server respond to the FQDN would indeed be the best option.